# Why did Jesus not write any scripture himself?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, scriptures

Did Jesus write any of His own scripture or contribute to the Bible directly?

If not, I do not understand why Jesus would not think to do that?

Is there a reason stated anywhere and what is the common Christian view of this?

Comment: I don't have a proven answer, but I do wonder if it is so that we don't try to venerate what he says, rather focus on what he does. I have similar thoughts as to why we may not have original copies of the books of the bible - if we did would we "worship" these original texts instead of read them and worship God?

Comment: What do you mean by `contribute to the Bible directly?` The Bible as we see now did not even exist in Jesus' time.

Comment: Do you mean to ask `Why did Jesus not Canonized the New Testament?`

Comment: Also, Jesus was God, not a prophet who write down the message of God.

Comment: There is no question to this that isn't pure speculation. Therefore, this does not fit within site guidelines. 
I'd invite you to read the [FAQ], as well as http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Answer (score 4):

**Contrary to what we might think, Jesus did not put teaching at the center of his mission. In fact he spent a lot of effort concealing his message through the use of parables.** In fact it was not until close to the end of his days in the flesh on this earth, that he promised to speak clearly by sending the Holy Ghost:

> “Though I have been speaking figuratively, a time is coming when I will no longer use this kind of language but will tell you plainly about my Father. In that day you will ask in my name. I am not saying that I will ask the Father on your behalf. (John 16:25-26, NIV)

One of the reasons for concealing his message was to keep his enemies in the dark, while giving some explanations to his disciples who would recall them later, after they had received the Spirit to understand. (Mark 4:33-34, John 14:25-26)

It seems that Jesus was more interested in dying and orchestrating the timing of his death than teaching.  His goal with regard to teaching was to be through the Spirit after his death and by the Apostles that he selected. Of couse this does not imply that his words recorded in the gospels are not filled with bottomless gold deposits of wisdom to mine from, but that his actions rather than parables are in the center.

**Considering his mission was to die and resurrect and not primarily to teach, except through his Apostles by the Spirit, it seems suitable that he would not write anything.**

Answer (score 2):

It's like asking "Why didn't God create<sup>1</sup> the Bible?".

God already created many things, the world, living things, human and the intelligence of man. God gave man the ability to think and He also gave freewill.

**What if God created<sup>1</sup> the Bible?** I do not see anything beneficial from it. Many will still doubt that it was forgery. There won't be any difference from the discovery of the Book of Mormon.

God wants his message to be conveyed by real people, heart to heart. Thus, we have a unique book. People from different time (around 1500 BC - 100 AD), writing in isolation from each other, but the goal is same, the message is same, the idea is same and the Author is One. All these characteristics of the Bible make it unique and credible. It's not like Qur'an which was written by one man, conveying his ideas and his alone.

God, of course, once gave a book to man<sup>2</sup>, written with His own divine hands, which was the Two Tablets of The Ten Commandments. But God had hidden it so that no one may discover it. God did this because He wants his book to be written by real people.

Thus, there is no need for Jesus to write any Scripture. After all, all the Words of Scriptures are fulfilled in him.

My favorite words from this [post](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14022/are-there-any-references-to-four-canonical-gospels-prior-to-100-ad)

> **A Natural Delivery**
>
> - The NT was NOT dropped from heaven.
> - The NT was NOT delivered by an angel.
> - The NT was NOT dug up in a farmer's field as golden plates like the Book of Mormon.
> - The NT was NOT suddenly "discovered" in a clay jar with 27 "books" intact like the Dead  - Sea Scrolls or the Nag Hammadi texts.
>
> The NT canon developed, or evolved, over the course of the first
> 250-300 years of Christian history. If the NT had been delivered by an
> angel, or unearthed as a complete unit it would not be as believable.
> Part of the historical validity of the NT comes from the fact that we
> can trace its development, albeit not as precisely as we might like.

---

<sub>1  to make something exist out of nothing</sub>

<sub>2  Moses, the writer of Torah</sub>

Comment: Your answer leads me to these thoughts. Actually what we Christians have in the form of Bible is as good as from God and that is the work of Trinity. All writers of Bible Books were inspired by Holy Spirit, the third person of Trinity and what else could we ask from God. Whether written by Jesus or inspired by Holy Spirit is one and the same, it is word of God.

Comment: God did create the Bible. He created everything. Are you sure you mean to say what you're saying in the first part? There's a difference between writing and creating (in the Divine sense of the word).

Comment: @Alypius By 'create' I mean 'dropped from heaven' or 'written with God's own hands'. If Jesus is God, then it's the same like Old Testament times, God instructed people to write.

Comment: God did not drop the world or the intelligence of man or freewill from heaven (2nd paragraph)

Comment: I am not expert with what the word 'create' exactly means. I always thought that God's 'creation' was to bring something out of nothing.

Comment: @Mawia Then God did create the Bible out of nothing. He created all of creation out of nothing, including the Bible. But that doesn't mean He wrote it. You might easily address this by replacing "created" with wrote, and delete the first two paragraphs.

Comment: I don't see any problem with God (well except for the two tablets of stone) or Jesus Christ writing / authoring scriptures themselves. They simply didn't and use human agents as means to communicate (and write down) their words/message.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus did numerous miracles when He walked on this earth. All these miracles are the manifestation of His ability to do “anything and everything”. He was able to do anything and everything” but thought it fit to do whatever He did and stop there and there,  not because He was not able to do, **but in God’s Wisdom,  that was fit to be so and sufficient to strengthen the faith of those who were destined to be saved**. Miracles like multiplying of bread and fish, telling Peter to get the coin from the first fish that he gets to pay for their taxes, ensuring that a colt and an ass is present at a designated place for His journey to Jerusalem, ensuring that a large room is ready for His last Supper, are but few which showed that He was capable of doing everything and anything.

In similar manner He could have made the Bible to come into existence during His stay on earth with single word from His mouth without even writing it, but He had a different plan. Jesus says:

> John 14:26 But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you everything, and will cause you to remember everything I said to you.

So to answer the question: Did Jesus write any of His own scripture or contribute to the Bible directly? Yes. Very much so. Through Holy Spirit.

What we Christians have in the form of Bible is certainly the work of "Holy Trinity one God". Since all writers of Bible Books were inspired by Holy Spirit, the third person of Holy Trinity, what else could we ask from God. Whether written by Jesus or inspired by Holy Spirit is one and the same, it is Word of God.